# share variable between two shared objects

Tags: c++, c, linux

Maybe it is a silly question, but so far I'm unable to find a direct answer to it. Is it possible to share variable between two shared objects (.so)?
For example: define global variable in one library and declare it as extern in another. My answer would be - "No", but I can't explain why.

Comment: why not? think about old implementation of `errno` from standard C library. You -shouldn't- do that (because it's still a global variable), but you can.

Comment: yes you can. The issue is that any executable that links to the library is forced to link to other one, which creates a dependency (tight coupling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course.

If it were not possible to use symbols defined within a shared library, they would have no purpose.

In the case that you're referring to the symbol from *another* shared library, your final executable must of course [dynamically] link to both.